# How can I use the deprecated function SetAngle?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everybody,
In my plugin I want to set the angle of a revolute joint according with a particular dynamic.
To do this I used the function

```
void gazebo::physics::Joint::SetAngle ( unsigned int  _index, math::Angle  _angle)
```

This function in declared as GAZEBO_DEPRECATED(version).
When I try to compile the code, I have this return :

```
warning: 'void gazebo::physics::Joint::SetAngle(unsigned int, gazebo::math::Angle)' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/gazebo-5.2/gazebo/physics/joint.hh:396 [-Wdeprecated-declaretions].
```

I'm not able to understand why I can't use this function.
Is there a  method that enables the user to use this type of function?

I tried to add this piece of code :

```
 #if defined(__GNUC__)
 #define GAZEBO_DEPRECATED(version) __attribute__((deprecated))
 #define GAZEBO_FORCEINLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
 #elif defined(_WIN32)
 #define GAZEBO_DEPRECATED(version)
 #define GAZEBO_FORCEINLINE __forceinline
 #else
 #define GAZEBO_DEPRECATED(version) ()
 #define GAZEBO_FORCEINLINE
 #endif
```

But appears an error like:

```
may not appear in macro parameter list
#define GAZEBO_FORCEINLINE __attribute__((always_inline))
```

Otherwise, is there other functions that can make the same thing of SetAngle?

Thank you, bye!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12742/how-can-i-use-the-deprecated-function-setangle?/) by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know how to use a deprecated function (maybe it depends on the gazebo version you use).

The new function should be *SetPosition* .

https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gabri89](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2451/gabri89/) on 2016-02-29**:
Thank you, the error disappears! I hope that the joint will behave as I want.